# Read Excel 2007 file (.xlsx) in C#

Tags: c#, excel-2007, xlsx

My code was quite sufficient for reading xls file in C# (using Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0) but when I tried to read Office 2007 (xlsx) file, it didn't work. I searched and found that it could be read using Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12, I tried and it worked. Can anyone tell me the difference between the two ? and why xlsx file can not be read using Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0 Provider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ACE` (Access Database Engine) is just the successor to `Jet`, it's still backwards compatible but it also supports new features in it's new default .accdb file format.

You can find more information at the Wiki page:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine

Here's a good blog post that goes into more detail:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20100710154150/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/access/archive/2005/10/13/480870.aspx)